# App Icon not Showing in some Android Devices

Tags: android, react-native, appicon

[In some android devices ,My App is not showing in app Drawer although it is installed and it can be seen in manage app also.But in App drawer it is not visible in some devices and also in search of application.
This is my AndroidMenifest.xml file.

I expect the icon to be visible.Even I am using adaptive icons

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tagmedia.adnan">
    
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.twitter.android" />
    </queries>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <receiver
            android:name=".AdnanWidgetProvider"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/adnan_widget" />
        </receiver>
        
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```